# How can I instantiate class with Member function pointer as template arg

Tags: c++, templates

I have

```
template <void (*T)(Entity *), typename Caller>
class Updater 
{
public:
    Updater(Caller c):m_caller(c){}
    void process(Entity * e)
    {
        (m_caller->*T)(e);              //Is this right?
    }
private:
    Caller m_caller;
};
```

I understand I can instantiate it like

```
Foo f;
Updater<&Foo::Bar> updater(&f);
```

assuming that `Foo` has

```
void Foo::Bar(Entity *e);
```

but what if it has desired method tempated? Like this

```
template <typename T>
void Bar(T t);
```

how shoult I instanciate it? Like this:?

```
Foo f;
Updater<&Foo::Bar<Entity *>> updater(&f);
```

When I do this in my real code, I get

`invalid template argument for ..., expected compile-time constant expression`

So 2 questions:

1, is `(m_caller->*T)(e);` correct? If it is not, how shout i call it?

2, how can I instantiate it?

Comment: Are you sure you have no space between the >'s in Updater<&Foo::Bar<Entity *>> updater(&f); ?

Comment: @Steed it is called "right-angle brackets" and it is perfectly fine in c++11, see http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#brackets

Comment: I don't think `Updater<&Foo::Bar>` is correct, &Foo::Bar is a pointer to member function, but your template parameter is a pointer to function, they are not the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <typename Caller, void (Caller::*Func)(Entity *)>
class Updater 
{
public:
    Updater(Caller *c):m_caller(c){}
    void process(Entity * e)
    {
        (m_caller->*Func)(e); // use pointer to member operator ->*
    }
private:
    Caller *m_caller;
};

// call like this
Foo f;
Updater<Foo, &Foo::Bar> updater(&f);
```

Comment: thank you, few comment though. 1, this calls the non-templated version, I found, that for templated version I have to use it like `&Foo2::template bar<Entity *>`,  and 2, `template <void (Celler::*Func)(Entity *), typename Caller>` does not work for me, I have to switch the arguments and pass both of them, which compiler do you use?

Comment: I have fixed the typo "Celler" -> "Caller".
I guess it should be fine now...
I have not tested, but I have written similar code before.

Comment: compiling with msvc2010 and getting `error C2653: 'Caller' : is not a class or namespace name`

Comment: so it is not possible to let compiler deduce the caller?

Comment: no in this case, since &Foo::Bar actually does not provide type Foo info (strangely).

Answer (score 0):

**edit:**

user2k5 edited his answer, so I accepted it.

**my previous msg:**

Thanks to user2k5 I figured out the right working code,

working sample follows: (Foo2 can be replaced by Foo)

```
#include <iostream>

struct Entity { int i; };

template < typename Caller, void (Caller::*Func)(Entity *)>
class Updater 
{
public:
    Updater(Caller *c):m_caller(c){}
    void process(Entity * e)
    {
        (m_caller->*Func)(e);
    }
private:
    Caller *m_caller;
};

struct Foo
{
    void bar(Entity * e) 
    {
        std::cout << e->i << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Foo2
{
    template <typename T>
    void bar(T t)
    {
        std::cout << t->i << std::endl;
    }
};

int main ()
{
    Foo2 f;
    Updater<Foo2, &Foo2::template bar<Entity *>> updater(&f);
    Entity e;
    e.i = 5;
    updater.process(&e);


    return 0;
}
```